# Importing .ipnyb file from Kaggle into local Jupyter

Tags: jupyter, kaggle

Total beginner question here, please let me know if it would be more appropriate somewhere else.

I just created my first iPython notebook in Kaggle and I downloaded the ipnyb file. Now I have installed Jupyter locally and want to try working on the same notebook that way.

It seems like I got Jupyter working because I am able to create a new local notebook and it looks like what I would expect:

[image]

But when I open the ipnyb file that I downloaded from Kaggle, I just see what looks like raw JSON instead of a live notebook:

[image]

I also noticed that the icons of these two notebook files look different:

[image]

Any suggestions about what I might be doing wrong and how I might get my properly import my Kaggle notebook into Jupyter locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because **"ipnyb"** is not proper format. Try downloading/changing it properly to **.ipynb** extension.

Comment: Doh! That's a helpful hint.

Comment: When I tried re-exporting later, it worked. Not sure what I did differently this time, but I'm glad it is working.